# How can I solve the translation of promises?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I'm newbie angular2. I'm making a website to start playing this platform. The problem is that when I query the API news can not transform objects correctly. Although I think there is a problem with the promises.

The code component is as follows:

```
import { Component }        from '@angular/core';
import { Router }           from '@angular/router';

import { AuthenticationService }   from '../Service/Authentication.service';
import { NoticiesService }         from '../Service/Noticies.service';
import { Logger }                  from '../Service/Logger.service';
import { Noticia }                 from '../Model/Noticia';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    templateUrl: 'app/View/html/Home.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/Content/css/app.component.css'],
})

export class HomeComponent {

    llistaNoticies: Noticia[];
    missNoticies = 'Noticies Actuals:';
    authenticatedUser = localStorage.getItem('usuari');
    sessionUp = this._serviceAuthentication.isSession;

    constructor(
        private _logger: Logger,
        private _serviceAuthentication: AuthenticationService,
        private _noticiesService: NoticiesService) { }

    getNoticies(): void {
        this._noticiesService.getNoticies()
        .then(noticies => this.llistaNoticies = noticies);
        console.log('getNoticies() passat!')
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.getNoticies()
        console.log('ngOnInit() passat!')
    }

    logOut() {
        this._serviceAuthentication.logOut();
    }
}
```

The Code of Service is:

```
import { Injectable }           from '@angular/core';
import { Router }               from '@angular/router';
import { Http, Response,
    Headers, RequestOptions }   from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Noticia }               from '../Model/Noticia';

@Injectable()
export class NoticiesService {

    private URLNoticies = 'http://localhost:50541/api/Noticies';

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _http: Http) { }

    getNoticies(): Promise<Noticia[]> {
        return this._http.get(this.URLNoticies)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as Noticia[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
    }

}
```

The component of HTML code:

```
<div class="block-general m-t-1 subTitolPag">
    <h2 class="titolPag">Notícies d'actualitat:</h2>
</div>

<div class="row p-a-1">
    <div id="block-central" class="block-sub col-md-6 offset-md-2">
        <div *ngFor="let noticia of llistaNoticies">
            <hr />

            <div class="card">

                <img class="card-img-top imgNoticia" src="{{noticia.PathImatge}}" alt="Card image cap" style="max-width: 100%;">

                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title titolNoticia">{{noticia.Titol}}</h4>

                    <p class="card-text">{{noticia.Cos}}</p>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <h5 class="pull-xs-right">Autor: <span class="label label-default pull-xs-right">{{noticia.Autor}}</span></h5>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h6 class="pull-xs-right">Data de: {{noticia.Data}}</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 block-sub m-x-1 p-a-1">
        <p>Usuari registrat: <span class="text-uppercase">{{authenticatedUser}}</span></p>
        <div class="clearfix m-t-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-xs-right" (click)="logOut()">Desconecta</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the class:

```
export class Noticia {
    public Id: number;
    public Titol: string;
    public Cos: string;
    public Autor: string;
    public PathImage: string;
    public Data: Date;
}
```

If someone finds where is the error and tell me where I can find clear promises would be very grateful.

Thank you!!

Comment: is there a special reason to use `Promise` instead of `Observable`?

Comment: No, I'm just researching and tutorial that followed the official website did well Angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `Observable`s.

```
@Injectable()
export class NoticiesService {

    private URLNoticies = 'http://localhost:50541/api/Noticies';

    constructor(
        private _router: Router,
        private _http: Http) { }

    getNoticies(): Observable<Noticia[]> {
        return this._http.get(this.URLNoticies)
            .map(response => response.json().data as Noticia[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: any): Observable<any> {
        console.error('An error occurred', error);
        return Observable.of(error.message || error);
    }
}
```

And consume your service:

```
getNoticies(): void {
    this._noticiesService.getNoticies()
    .subscribe(
       noticies => this.llistaNoticies = noticies,
       err => console.log(err)
    );
    console.log('getNoticies() passat!')
}
```